# laravel how to get all the models except one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `restaurant` model and a `waitingtime` model. the relationship is one to many, **everything is working , I am able to update, edit and delete**

I can get all the waitingtimes for a specific restaurant like this

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $res = Restaurant::find(4);
        $allWaitingTimesForThisRestaurant = $res->waitingtimes()->get();
```

That gives me an array and I am happy with using it in my jquery when the page return.

#### My question

is there any way so I still able to get all the waitingtimes for a specific restuarant **but without a specific waitingtime**

for example, the input to the edit function is `$id`, and this `$allWaitingTimesForThisRestaurant = $res->waitingtimes()->get();` returns an array of waitingtimes, so I need that array but without the waitingtime with the `id=$id`

can you help me please?

I feel that I didn't explain my problem well, if so kindly tell me to explain more.

many tnanks

Comment: Do you want all `WaitingTime` for a particular restaurant except **one** with a given `id`?

Comment: @PatrickReck yes exactly.

Comment: @PatrickReck no help please?

Comment: I just submitted an answer. You can see it below this comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use a regular where?

```
$res = Restaurant::find(4);
$allWaitingTimesForThisRestaurant = $res->waitingtimes()->where('id', '!=', $res)->get();
```

Edit: Also, see Hailwood's comment below for a good addendum.

Comment: You should probably add a note about how the method ->waitingtimes() vs ->waitingtimes returns a query builder instance so you can use any methods on there.

Comment: Many thanks, it works, and I am sorry I am not able to upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputations

Comment: What a good solution, thank you, Sir! I've struggle with myself for hours for this. When I read your answer, I've instantly remembered what docs said about calling ->method and method() are two different things. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way using the least code, is by removing it after retrieving them all.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $res = Restaurant::find(4);
    $allWaitingTimesForThisRestaurant = $res->waitingtimes()->get();

    foreach($allWaitingTimesForThisRestaurant as $restaurant) {
        if ($restaurant->id == $id) unset($restaurant);
    }
```

As far as I remember, you will have to write the SQL on your own if you don't want to remove it afterwards.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but the other answer as better. I can't upvote your question because I don't have enough reputation, many thanks